Need to know which are cultures are supported for TextBlock.IsHyphenationEnabled
I'm currently working on a WPF application and using the TextBlock.IsHyphenationEnabled property to handle text hyphenation. I understand that hyphenation behavior can be culture-specific, and I'm trying to ensure proper functionality across different languages.
Could anyone provide a list of cultures that are officially supported for hyphenation when using the TextBlock.IsHyphenationEnabled property? Specifically, I'm interested in knowing if languages like Swedish (sv-SE), German (de-DE), and others are fully supported.
I see some code related to it but not sure how culture support is done:
Class: NaturalLanguageHyphenator
 public override bool IsCultureSupported(CultureInfo culture)
 {
    // Accept all cultures for the time being. Ideally, NL6 should provide a way for the client to test supported culture.
    return true;
 }

Additionally, if any specific settings or configurations are required on the client machine, such as installing language packs in Windows
Code and debugging values for TextBlock and Culture info (sv-SE not working here)
<TextBlock IsHyphenationEnabled="True" 
Text="{Binding Name}" Language="sv-SE"
TextWrapping="Wrap"/>

System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture - en-IN System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture - sv
Any documentation or experiences you can share would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your help.

Not sure, what you are asking but accordingly to documentation "Words are broken and hyphenated according to standard grammar rules." if you enable the property. So I guess you can set it to true and WPF hyphenation mechanism will take care of the rest.

This is not an answer, but it may help in the investigation.
As you may suspect, Hyphenation is done with the use of native dll. Most probably it is C:\Windows\System32\NaturalLanguage6.dll at very end.
There is a PresentationNative_xxxxx.dll in the middle, but it doesn't matter right now. NL6 team doesn't provide a way for the client to test supported culture, as we can read from the comment.
NaturalLanguage6.dll exports 4 functions: DllCanUnloadNow, DllGetClassObject, DllRegisterServer and DllUnregisterServer so it's a COM library.
I've found 4 CLSIDs related to this dll: {0E1EEFB2-E336-481C-B178-36261EC5A843}, {333E6924-4353-4934-A7BE-5FB5BDDDB2D6}, {89EA5B5A-D01C-4560-A874-9FC92AFB0EFA} and {D385FDAD-D394-4812-9CEC-C6575C0B2B38}, but I can't find much more. I tried to use OleView.exe to inspect NaturalLanguage6.dll, but it failed.
To make thing worse, there is no guarantee that PresentationNative_xxxxx.dll uses NaturalLanguage6.dll, especially on platforms different than Windows.
Anyway it seems that:

.NET team doesn't know which cultures are supported,
functionality is buried deep in Windows system dlls,
supported cultures may change with Windows updates.

Since it's pointless to call PresentationNative's methods (there's none that would help), the next likely step will be to decompile the dll to see what's inside.

Oleview.exe is the way to see what's inside.  Run it elevated to let it register itself, you only have to do that once.  You however won't find much of interest in the type library, it passes the job of hyphenation to another module, possibly elshyph.dll, where the trail goes cold.  The api is too clunky, no doubt the reason why the .net wrapper is lame as well.  A machine that boots the Swedish language version of Windows might be able to do it.

IsHyphenationEnabled works with any culture language that:

Is installed (e.g. via Language Pack)
Has a valid LCID (i.e. not 4096)

To determine which languages are installed, you can use the GetInstalledInputLanguages() method in this answer.
Then, to determine which cultures allow for hyphenation, we can use this method:
private static ICollection<CultureInfo> GetInstalledCultures()
{
    var languages = GetInstalledInputLanguages()
        .Select(c => c.TwoLetterISOLanguageName)
        .ToHashSet();

    var cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
        .Where(c => c.LCID != 4096)
        .Where(c => languages.Contains(c.TwoLetterISOLanguageName))
        .ToList();

    return cultures;
}

On my system, I have en-US and en-GB installed which yield the following hyphenation-enabled cultures:

en, en-029, en-AU, en-BZ, en-CA, en-GB, en-HK, en-ID, en-IE, en-IN,
en-JM, en-MY, en-NZ, en-PH, en-SG, en-TT, en-US, en-ZA, en-ZW


I have already tried all 800+ cultures (automated). Only the ones I listed allow for hyphenation on my machine. Don't have extra languages installed. Not sure if installing Swedish would make it work. Maybe NL6 only supports English?
